# From elementary substructures to embeddings

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic

I have some questions about the relationship from elementary substructures to elementary embeddings. It is clear how to go from elementary embeddings to substructures.

Given an nontrivial elementary embedding $\pi:V\to M$ ($\pi$ surjective, $M$ transitive) we have that $M$ is is an elementary substructure and we can define the critical point $\kappa:=\min\left\{ \alpha<On\mid\pi\left(\alpha\right)\neq\alpha\right\}$  and the ultrafilter $U:=\left\{ a\subseteq\kappa\mid\kappa\in\pi\left(a\right)\right\}$ .

Conversely, given a proper elementary substructure $M\subset V$ can I directly define $\kappa$ and $U$?

Another way of putting the question is if $\pi,\pi^{\prime}:V\to M$ are both elementary then must they both have the same critical point and ultrafilter? I would guess $\kappa=\left\{ \alpha<On\mid\alpha\notin M\right\}$  and so does not depend on $\pi$, but $U:=\left\{ a\subseteq\kappa\mid\kappa\in\pi\left(a\right)\right\}$  and $U^{\prime}:=\left\{ a\subseteq\kappa\mid\kappa\in\pi^{\prime}\left(a\right)\right\}$  do depend on $\pi$ and $\pi^{\prime}$ but are related somehow.

I believe I can use elementarity to prove the existence of elementary embeddings $V\to M$ and some of their properties. Suppose transitive $M$ is definable by statement $\varphi$ so the statement

$\zeta_{M} := \exists f\left(Function\left[f\right]\wedge\psi_{f,M}^{\prime}\wedge\psi_{f,M}^{\prime\prime}\wedge\psi_{f}^{\prime\prime\prime}\right)$

where

$\psi_{f,M}^{\prime} := \forall x\left(f\left(x\right)\in M\right)$

$\psi_{f,M}^{\prime\prime} := \forall x\left(x\in M\to f\left(x\right)=x\right)$

$\psi_{f}^{\prime\prime\prime} := \forall u,v\left(\left(u=v\leftrightarrow f\left(u\right)=f\left(v\right)\right)\wedge\left(u\in v\leftrightarrow f\left(u\right)\in f\left(v\right)\right)\right)$

can be expressed in 1st order set language.

Now $\zeta_{M}$ is witnessed by the identity function on $M$ so by elementarity $V\vDash\zeta_{M}$ so let $\pi$ witness $\zeta_{M}$ in V then $\pi:V\to M$ and is surjective by $\psi_{f,M}^{\prime}\wedge\psi_{f,M}^{\prime\prime}$ and preserves and reflects $=$ and $\in$ by $\psi_{f}^{\prime\prime\prime}$ (note reflecting $=$ makes $\pi$ injective). By $\psi_{f}^{\prime\prime\prime}$ and induction on the formation rules of statements I believe we can show $\pi$ is elementary.

If $\pi^{\prime}$ also witnesses $\zeta_{M}$ in $V$ then $\pi\left(x\right)=x=\pi^{\prime}\left(x\right)$ for $x\in M$ by $\psi_{f,M}^{\prime\prime}$. This gives $M\cap U=M\cap U^{\prime}$ because $a\in M\cap U$ iff $a\in M$ and $a\subseteq\kappa$ and $\kappa\in\pi\left(a\right)$ iff $a\in M$ and $a\subseteq\kappa$ and $\kappa\in\pi^{\prime}\left(a\right)$ iff $a\in M\cap U^{\prime}$.

If the above has logical flaws please help me understand them. If the above is correct, am I right about $\kappa$ being definable from $M$ only, but the ultrafilter depends on $\pi$, and if $\pi,\pi^{\prime}$ are two such embeddings their ultrafilters are related by $M\cap U=M\cap U^{\prime}$. What more can be said about all of this?

Answer (score 3):

There several errors here. Most importantly are the two mistakes occurring when you claim

> Given an nontrivial elementary embedding $\pi:V\to M$ ($\pi$ surjective, $M$ transitive) we have that $M$ is is an elementary substructure

First of all, your elementarity is going the wrong way. The image of $\pi$ - call it "$\pi[V]$" for simplicity - is an elementary substructure (well, sub*class*structure) of $M$, but $M$ need not be an elementary substructure of $V$. Indeed, it usually won't be: e.g. taking $\pi$ to be the embedding coming from the first measurable, what $M$ thinks is the first measurable will in fact be much bigger than the first measurable.

*EDIT: I missed the obvious fact that elementarity of this form can **never** happen: if $W$ is an inner model (= transitive proper class satisfying ZF), then $W\not\preccurlyeq V$ unless $W=V$. (Proof: by elementarity we have $(V_\alpha)^W=V_\alpha$ for every ordinal $\alpha$. Since $W$ is transitive we have $W=\bigcup_{\alpha\in Ord} (V_\alpha)^W=\bigcup_{\alpha\in Ord} V_\alpha=V$.)*

Conversely, if $M\prec V$ there is no reason to believe that there is an elementary embedding from $V$ into $M$; rather, all we know is that the inclusion map is elementary from $M$ to $V$.

Secondly, $\pi$ is **never surjective**: the critical point of $\pi$ will never be in the image of $\pi$! If $\pi(a)=crit(\pi)$, by elementarity (and absoluteness) we must have $a$ be an ordinal; $\pi(crit(\pi))\not=\pi$, we have $a\not=crit(\pi)$, that is $\pi(a)\not=a$. But since $crit(\pi)$ is by definition the least ordinal moved by $\pi$, this tells us $a>crit(\pi)$. But now we have $$a>crit(\pi)\quad\mbox{ but }\quad \pi(a)<\pi(crit(\pi)),$$ contradicting elementarity.

A lesser issue: you also seem to assume that an elementary substructure is definable ("Suppose transitive $M$ is definable by statement $\varphi$"), which is in general not the case. *(Of course, the image of an elementary embedding which is "set-generated" (e.g. coming from a measure) will be definable with a parameter; but note that that parameter will move when we apply the embedding!)*

Finally, you claim

> Now $\zeta_M$ is witnessed by the identity function on $M$

But this is not necessarily true! Just knowing that $M$ is definable *in $V$* doesn't mean that the *same definition* pins down $M$ inside $M$. (That is, even if $M=\varphi^V$ we may still have $\varphi^M\not=M$.) The classic example of this is that while $L\models$ $"V=L,"$ we in general **need not** have $HOD\models$ $"V=HOD"$. And it should be clear that this is an issue, since if $M\subsetneq V$ then there is no class function from $V$ to $M$ which is the identity on $M$ and is injective so you can't build $\pi$ in $V$ as you suggest.

---

That said, there is an interesting question here once we clear away the issues mentioned above:

> How much of an elementary embedding is determined by the target model $M$?

First, a very silly answer (working in [ZF instead of ZFC for the moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kunen%27s_inconsistency_theorem)): if there are two [Reinhardt cardinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinhardt_cardinal), then we know that the critical point can't be determined from the target model since both Reinhardt embeddings have target model $V$. *Sorry, couldn't resist.*

More seriously, even knowing the target model *and the critical point* won't pin down the embedding or even the corresponding measure *(note that in general the embedding **cannot** be recovered from the induced measure!)*, even up to "reasonable equivalence;" for more details, look up the [**Mitchell order**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/53441/equivalent-ways-to-describe-the-mitchell-order).

This leaves open the question of whether the critical point can be determined from the target. I believe the answer is no. As partial evidence for this, note that from any measurable $\kappa$ we can extract an elementary embedding of $L$ into itself with critical point $\kappa$. However, this doesn't quite count since the domain is $L$, rather than $V$ itself.

Comment: Thanks, so to clarify when we say $\pi:V\to M$ is an elementary embedding it is never the case that $\pi\left[V\right]=M$, so the role of $M$ is simply to provide a transitive class for the elementary substructure $\pi\left[V\right]$ to live in?

Comment: @MarkKortink Basically yes, but I worry that downplays $M$. Think about the usual measure situation. We have a measure $\mu$ on a cardinal $\kappa$. From $\mu$ we form as usual the ultrapower map $m: V\rightarrow\prod_\kappa V/\mu$, ignoring for the moment the coding issues in defining this precisely. Since $\mu$ is a measure, $\prod_\kappa V/\mu$ is well-founded (and it's clearly extensional and set-like) so we can apply the appropriate Mostowski collapse map $c$. The target model $M$ is the collapse of $\prod_\kappa V/\mu$, and our embedding $j$ is the composition of $c$ and $m$. (cont'd)

Comment: Now let's think about the elements of $M$ which *aren't* in the image of $j$. These are the $c$-images of the elements of $\prod_\kappa V/\mu$ which aren't in the image of $m$, and these in turn are exactly the $\mu$-classes which don't contain constant sequences! In other words, the "extra stuff" in $M$ is far from random: things in $M$ have "names" coming from $V$, and the map $j$ assigns to each thing in $V$ a very special name (in this setting, the corresponding constant sequence). So $M$ is more than just "something containing the image of $j$," it's really important.